# Minimal number of colours in distinguishing colouring of biconnected graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory

A colouring of edges of a graph is *distingushing* if no non-identity automorphism of the graph preserves this colouring.

> **Problem.** Is it true that each biconnected graph possesses a distinguishing colouring using $1+\lceil\Delta^{1/\delta}\rceil$ colours?

Here $\Delta$ and $\delta$ stand for the largest and smallest degree of a vertex of the graph. The colouring needs not be proper, i.e., adjacent edges can be coloured by the same colour.

A graph is *biconnected* if it remains connected after removing any vertex and its incident edges.

(The problem is posed 07.04.2018 by Imrich, Kalinowski and Pilsniak on [page 21](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=21) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

**Prize for solution**: Strudel i kawa przed seminarium w Katedrze matematyki dyskretnej AGH, na ktorym autor przedstawi rozwiazanie.

Comment: Usually, MO is not meant to simply state known open problems, see for example "https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/360/what-should-be-the-policy-on-open-problems-on-mo"

Comment: @verret You are right. The problems should be original posed by the authors of the posts in Lviv Scottish Book. Could you please give a link to a source where this concrete problem has been posed or discussed. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaban-5 Indeed, this seems to be a counteexample. Please write it as a formal answer and I will try to contact the authors of this problem. According to their promise (written in the Lviv Scottish Book), they should invite you to deliver a talk on their seminar in AGH, Krakow (it is a nice tourist city :)

Comment: @Kaban-5 I have contacted the authours of this problem and one of them wrote me that they had in mind edge colouring writing "kolorowanie grafu", not vertex colouring. So I made a wrong translation of this question into English. Sorry for that. For the edge colourings you example $K_{n,n}$ does not fit as this graph admits a distinguishing edge colouring with 2 colours (I do not see which exactly), but an author of the problem wrote that because $K_{n,n}$ is tracable.

Comment: @Kaban-5 Oh, sorry! I did not read the problem carefully enough and translated "dwospojny" (i.e., biconnected) as "bipartite". This was a reason of  misunderstanding. Now it is corrected to biconnected. Maybe it is reasonable just to delete all comments related to bipartite graphs to avoid further mesunderstanding (of future readers)?

Comment: @Kaban-5 Yes, indeed. Thank you for this comment. I have changed the explanation of proper colouring. So, now we can remove all our comments?

Comment: Yes, everything seems fine now.